# data import ideas

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee

I have developed a system where the admin user is expected to update the approval of xyz from another website which has the details. This is being done manually for many records. I am planning to automate it.

I am thinking of getting a csv file with approval details and import it on my system and update the system with approvals. In this also the admin user will have to import the csv file every day.

The project Environment is J2EE, oracle

Is there a better way to do it?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk data import and export is always better to handle [using the DB provided tools](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Data+Import+and+Export) (unless you have to run the data through some business rules which are only enforced in the application layer). If this is not much data then you can just process the file in the web-container and use [JDBC batch processing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm).

Comment: The data is not huge and I have some simple business rules to enforce.